# CSS vertical-align on an :after element

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

Here's what I'm working with:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
     ::after /* <-- This is just to illustrate where the :after is */
</div>
```

and here's my styling (it's SCSS, if you're not used to seeing nested styling.):

```
.page-header{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 2em;

    h1{
      display: table-cell;
      min-width: 156px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    &:after{
      display: table-cell;
      content: "";
      width: 86%;
      border-top: 3px solid #635c4d;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

For some reason, I can't seem to get the :after element to align vertically in the middle. It just stays at the top. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

i think you need `::after` and some content in the css

```css
.page-header{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 2em;
}
.page-header  h1{
    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 156px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.page-header::after{
    display: table-cell;
    content: "::after";
    width: 86%;
    border-top: 3px solid #635c4d;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <!-- This is just to illustrate where the :after is */ -->
</div>
```

Comment: No, I don't want any content in the :after element. The reason I made it is so that I could just make the border a horizontal line that is vertically aligned to the middle of the <h1> element. I just realized that display table-cell is going to make the two elements the same height by default, so I'll just have to find another way to do this. I was hoping I could use display table cell for responsive reasons, but it doesn't seem like it's going to be possible. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

So the reason that the elements won't vertically align is that I'm trying to get the top border to vertically align to the , however display:table/table-cell will make the :after element the same height as the , thus putting the border at the top of the two elements. I was trying to use table/table-cell for responsive reasons, so that the two elements wouldn't intersect, but since I'll never get the :after element's border to be vretically aligned in the middle of the , I'll just have to come up with another solution for responsiveness.